# Can I map incomplete sproc columns to an entity?

Tags: entity-framework

I am using the latest beta of Visual Studio 2010 and the Entity Framework.  It's mostly really neat, but here's my situation:

- I have a table T with columns `Id` and `Name`.
- I have an auto-generated entity with `Id` and `Name` properties.
- Finally, I have a stored procedure that selects only `Id` from T.

Trying to map my entity to the stored procedure results in an `EntityCommandExecutionException`:

> A member of [the entity], 'Name', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.

That makes sense, but **is there some way to partially populate my entity from the stored procedure call and then fully materialize it later with a second query?**

Nine months ago, [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753995/l2entities-stored-procedure-and-mapping) to this question appeared to involve a great deal of manual labor.  In my case, we have hundreds of stored procedures, and literally none of them return full rows.  The Entity Framework has come a long way since then, so I am hoping something might've changed.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Is it *really* the case that your entity has only `Id` and `Name`, or have you "simplified?"

Comment: It's simplified!  We do have hundreds of cases like this, however, so I felt I had to generalize somewhere.  How might it matter, out of curiosity?

Comment: Well, it's trivial to make EF 4 map a proc which returns a scalar, and `Id` is scalar, right? You can then materialize the "other" field via `Context.Ts.Where(t => t.Id == id).Single()`

Comment: Yes, you're right - I could get the entities manually.  Most would require mapping to a complex type rather than a scalar, but it could be done.

I was, naturally, hoping for something a bit more automatic. :-(

Comment: You could customize the T4 such that the complex types automatically get a method to materialize the entity....

Comment: That sounds more like what I was thinking, though I haven't a clue how to do that at the moment.  If you feel like going into a bit more detail in a full post, I'd be happy to mark this thing answered.  Otherwise, thank you for your efforts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach might be to map the procedure results into a complex type, and then customize the code generation to add a method to this type which will materialize the entire object.

One possible hitch with this idea is that I'm not sure it's possible to customize code generation for complex types. You can certainly customize code generation for entity types, [as explained in great detail in this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/efdesign/archive/2009/01/22/customizing-entity-classes-with-t4.aspx). It seems like you should be able to customize complex types, as well, but I've never tried it.